How can you programmatically insert "requestTimeout="00:30:00" via program.cs, rather than web.config
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that gets published to IIS on multiple dedicated customer web servers.
Is there a way to insert the:
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:30:00".../>

in program.cs?
I tried doing a timeout middleware but it appeared to have ignored the value of the timeout set on the controller, but when I added the
requestTimeout="00:30:00"

in the web.config, that one worked. I want to know if I can do it in program.cs as I do not want to have to have the customer inserting it manually into web.config.
Thanks

I don't think that's possible because the  configuration element is part of the web server's web.config in IIS and is not directly manipulated via the Program.cs in .NET 8. What's the reason you don't deploy the web.config with the app? Why would the customer need to insert it?

Thank you Jeremy for your reply.  I don't see web.config in my project to change it there, I only see it on the web server side.  I was thinking there might be a way maybe in the program.cs or maybe project file since I was able to edit the "OutOfProcess" in the project file and it shows up in the web.config as ""hostingModel="OutOfProcess" in the web.config.  But I'll drill down in the project itself to find web.config.  Thanks again.

You can do this via filter attribute decorated over your API,or you can configure you middle ware with request timeout policy
Decorate over API endpoint
[RequestTimeout(milliseconds: 2000)]
Through the middleware
`builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts(options => {
    options.DefaultPolicy =
        new RequestTimeoutPolicy { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500) };
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
});`

Please refer the link enter link description here

Thank you Mohan, I'll try doing the middleware again using your suggestion above and will post result.  Thanks again

@muttBunch If your application is running on Kestrel (before IIS reverse proxy), you can configure the Kestrel server timeout options in Program.cs - but to do it in IIS you need to include the web.config (create one if none exist) in your deployment. Its becoming increasingly rare these days to do On-Premise installs of websites, customers shouldn't be configuring any of this stuff unless due to security.
